# SVG feComponentTransfer to colorize image

Tags: svg, colors, rgb, svg-filters

I'm trying to colorize a white image using a filter but I'm getting an unexpected result

SVG Sample:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="373" height="400"
     viewBox="0 0 373 400">

    <defs>
        <filter id="colorize">
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.3333333"></feFuncR>
                <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0"></feFuncG>
                <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.3333333"></feFuncB>
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <g filter="url(#colorize)">
        <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/Df8zD8O.png" width="373" height="400"></image>
    </g>
    <text font-weight="bold" fill="rgb(85,0,85)" x="0" y="100" font-size="100">Surfer</text>

</svg>
```

The expected result is that the image becomes the same color as the text
In this case `#550055` or `rgb(85,0,85)`

I set the slopes on the filter to `0.3333333` for `R` and `B` based on the result of `85 / 255` but as you can see the result is not correct

Maybe I'm using the wrong method of calculation to attain the desired color

One thing to note is that colors having components approaching/equaling 255 give much better results

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="373" height="400"
     viewBox="0 0 373 400">

    <defs>
        <filter id="colorize">
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncR type="linear" slope="255"></feFuncR>
                <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0"></feFuncG>
                <feFuncB type="linear" slope="255"></feFuncB>
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <g filter="url(#colorize)">
        <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/Df8zD8O.png" width="373" height="400"></image>
    </g>
    <text font-weight="bold" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" x="0" y="100" font-size="100">Surfer</text>

</svg>
```

I based my calculation on this formula

```
C' = slope * C + intercept
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can make the text white and put it in the `<g>` with the filter

Comment: It's just an example to show the difference between the real color and the resulting color, but in reality the text is not part of the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default colour space for [most SVG filters is linearRGB](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#ColorInterpolationFiltersProperty). You seem to be assuming it's sRGB though.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="373" height="400"
     viewBox="0 0 373 400">

    <defs>
        <filter id="colorize" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.3333333"></feFuncR>
                <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0"></feFuncG>
                <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.3333333"></feFuncB>
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <g filter="url(#colorize)">
        <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/Df8zD8O.png" width="373" height="400"></image>
    </g>
    <text font-weight="bold" fill="rgb(85,0,85)" x="0" y="100" font-size="100">Surfer</text>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the color space to sRGB - because that's the color space that the CSS rgb() color property uses. (The default color space for SVG filters is linearRGB).

Add `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` to your filter element and you'll get the result you expect.